# multiple mp4 videos code for looping (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, mp4

```
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
mcV2.autoRewind = true;
mcV2.autoPlay = true;
function Loop(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void {
    mcV2.play();
}
mcV2.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.AUTO_REWOUND, Loop);
```

Its a good solution for looping mp4 video files, thx.

How can I use 2 (or more) videos with this code for loop?

etc: mcV1, mcV2, ../..

Comment: I sugest you to use the same solution if you believe it's good for looping video files. Just create an array with your videos and execute this scope in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will solve your problem:

```
var myArr = ["mcV1","mcV2","mcV3"]

for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
    var targetBox:FLVPlayback = this.getChildByName("mcV"+(i+1)) as FLVPlayback;
    targetBox.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.AUTO_REWOUND, Loop);
    targetBox.autoRewind = true;
    targetBox.autoPlay = true;
}

function Loop(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void {
    event.target.play();
}
```

I added the sample fla as well [FLA](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/sample.fla)

Comment: thank you very much Özgür. (a white flash frame appears when the movie is over but no problem)

Comment: great! if you find my answer useful please vote up and the others can see it is the right answer, happy coding!!! [ps if you share screen shot of your problem we can fix it maybe]

Comment: I tried but there is "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" sorry : ( 
did you see my new question? : )